# Recursion error while creating Asset which is having self-join relationship

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have defined Asset as :

```
 asset PurchaseOrderAsset identified by orderId {

    o String orderId

    --> SupplierChainParticipant createdBy

    --> SupplierChainParticipant assignedTo

    o String description    

    o String status

    o Integer quantity

    o String assetId

    o PurchaseOrderAsset[] subPurchaseOrders
}
```

Now, When I am trying to create Asset, I am getting error as "InternalError: too much recursion".  i am facing this error in composer playground.

Can we have self-join relationship or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, please create an issue for it, attaching your example BNA.

To workaround it I recommend that you create a `concept` for the line items of a purchase order. Conceptually those "sub" purchase orders are not assets, because they are not addressable through a registry.

Please also see: [Different between 'o' and arrow symbol used in .cto file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410459/different-between-o-and-arrow-symbol-used-in-cto-file)